# How does $\sqrt[6]{26+15\sqrt3}-\sqrt[6]{26-15\sqrt3}$ become $\sqrt2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

How can I simplify this?

$$\sqrt[6]{26+15\sqrt3}-\sqrt[6]{26-15\sqrt3}$$

I know the answer is $\sqrt2$, but don't know where to start.

Thx.

Comment: Write $x=\sqrt[6]{26+15*\sqrt3}-\sqrt[6]{26-15*\sqrt3}$, then start isolating those roots and make them go away by taking powers.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the expressions under radicals as follows $$26\pm15\sqrt3=\frac{1}{8}(\sqrt3\pm1)^6,$$ then
$$\sqrt[6]{26+15\sqrt3}-\sqrt[6]{26-15\sqrt3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]8}(\sqrt3+1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]8}(\sqrt3-1)=\sqrt2$$

---

EDIT

In school exercises, sometimes it is useful to find a different writing of the given expression in order to get a nice result. Here we know that the result is nice and simple.

First of all, realize that $\sqrt[6]A=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt A}.$
It would be nice to find rational numbers $p,q$ so that $$26\pm15\sqrt3=(p\pm q\sqrt3)^2.$$
However, $(a+b\sqrt3)^2=a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt3,$ and I was hoping to find **integers** $a,b.$ Thus I multiplied LHS by $2$ and solved
$$52+30\sqrt3=a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt3 \quad (a,b\in\mathbb{Q}),$$
that is equivalent to the system
\begin{cases}
a^2+3b^2&=&52 \quad &\text{rational part}\\
2ab\sqrt3&=&30\sqrt3 \quad &\text{irrational part}
\end{cases}
That gives $$2(26+15\sqrt3)=(5+3\sqrt3)^2$$
For $(26-15\sqrt3)$ we get $a,b$ with opposite signs:
$$2(26-15\sqrt3)=(5-3\sqrt3)^2$$
Sixth root is positive, hence
$$\sqrt[6]{26\pm15\sqrt3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]2}\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt3\pm5}.$$

Again, I tried to find integers $x,y$ such that $$(x+y\sqrt3)^3=k(3\sqrt3+5)$$ for a constant $k,$ preferably integral. The principle of computation was as above. The constant turned out to be again $k=2.$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful technique [using the following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509357/prove-that-sqrt318-sqrt325-sqrt318-sqrt325-3-without-u/3509395#3509395)

> If $a+b+c=0$ then $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc \tag{1}$

Now, let's note
$$x=\sqrt[6]{26+15\sqrt3}-\sqrt[6]{26-15\sqrt3}$$
Obviously (or easy to check)
$$x>0 \tag{2}$$
Then, using $\left(26+15\sqrt{3}\right)\left(26-15\sqrt{3}\right)=1$, we have
$$x^2+2=\sqrt[3]{26+15\sqrt3}+\sqrt[3]{26-15\sqrt3}$$
or
$$(x^2+2)+\left(-\sqrt[3]{26+15\sqrt3}\right)+\left(-\sqrt[3]{26-15\sqrt3}\right)=0$$
From $(1)$ this leads to
$$(x^2+2)^3-52=3(x^2+2)\tag{3}$$
It's not too difficult to check that $-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are roots of $(3)$.

Now, we divide $(3)$ (polynomial division) by $x^2-2$ and obtain
$$(2) \iff (x^2 - 2) (x^4 + 8 x^2 + 25) = 0$$
Or $\sqrt{2}$ is the only positive root, because $x^4 + 8 x^2 + 25 > 0$ and has no real roots. Thus, from $(2)$ we conclude that $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Nice approach, I upvote.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, notice $\sqrt[6]{26+15\sqrt3}$ and $\sqrt[6]{26-15\sqrt3}$ are reciprocals of each other. (Just multiply them together.) So if you let $a = \sqrt[6]{26+15\sqrt3}$, you are seeking to show that $a - {1 \over a} = \sqrt{2}$.

Squaring both sides, given that your expression is positive you can rewrite what you are trying to show as
$$a^2 + \frac{1}{a^2} = 4$$
Let $x =  a^2 + {1 \over a^2}$. Then
$$x^3 = a^6 + {1 \over a^6} + 3\bigg(a^2 + {1 \over a^2}\bigg)$$
Note that $a^6 + {1 \over a^6} = 26+15\sqrt3 + 26-15\sqrt3 = 52$, so the above
gives $$x^3 = 52 + 3x$$
The roots of $x^3 - 3x - 52 = 0$ are $4$, $-2 + 3i$, and $-2 - 3i$. Since $x$ is real, we must have $x = 4$ as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\sqrt[6]{26+15\sqrt3}-\sqrt[6]{26-15\sqrt3}$. Then $A^2=B-2$ where $B=\sqrt[3]{26+15\sqrt3}+\sqrt[3]{26-15\sqrt3}$.

On the other hand, $B$ satisfies the equation $B^3-3B-52=0$. We see that it has one real root which is $B=4$. Hence, $A=\sqrt2$.

Comment: Note: I just notice that my solution is very similar to rtybase's and I am 1 hour late. I didnt see it when I also analyzed the function $f(x)=x^3-3x-52$ by graph. It has really one real real root.